# Why is this static method slowly taking longer to complete?

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I have a static method that I use to process `ResultSets` and have it give back an object. Sometimes it can get called many times over and over again. For instance, in a current project I am working on, the static method gets called over 56,000 times. For whatever reason, as it gets called over and over and over again the method takes longer and longer to reply.

I've been using the `System.currentTimeMillis()` to figure out where in the code it keeps getting longer to complete, and though I know that the `currentTimeMillis()` is not 100% accurate, the time that it takes to complete this part of code slowly and repeatedly will increase with time.

Here is the code:

```
public static Object createFromResultSet(ResultSet someResultSet, String someIndex) throws SQLException, Exception {
    { ... }
    List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList();
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList();
    List<Object> addRow;

    // the code below will take longer and longer to complete as the method is called over and over again
    while (someResultSet.next()) {
        addRow = new ArrayList();
        for (int x = 0; x < columnNames.size(); x++) {
            if (someResultSet.getObject(x + 1) instanceof Double) {
                Double someValue = someResultSet.getDouble(x + 1);
                addRow.add(new BigDecimal(someValue).toPlainString());
            }
            else if (someResultSet.getObject(x + 1) != null) addRow.add(someResultSet.getObject(x + 1).toString());
            else addRow.add("");
        }
        result.add(addRow.toArray());
    } 
    { ... }
}
```

Maybe I don't completely understand how static methods work in Java, but I would think that all variables in this method would only be used once within the time that the static method is called (ie, if the method is called again, there are no values carried over from the previous time the method was called). Other than the variables that are being passed in, there are no static variables that are being used that were declared outside the method. However, the method becomes slower and slower over time leading me to believe there is data that is being used from previous calls to this method. In the 56,000 times that it is called in my current project, it can take up to an hour for this report to run.

Something tells me I have something wrong in my logic, but for the likes of me I have no clue what's happening.

Comment: *Theory:* You don't release your resources (memory leak), and system is spending more and more time doing GC runs.

Comment: @Andreas so let's say you are correct. How do I release my resources in a language that does its own GC?

Comment: Why are you adding values to an `ArrayList`, just to call `toArray()` at the end, when you know the array size up front (`columnNames.size()`)? Replace `addRow = new ArrayList();` with `Object[] row = new Object[columnNames.size()];`. Using `ArrayList` generates unnecessary garbage.

Comment: To release your resources, you make sure that the caller of `createFromResultSet` closes the `ResultSet` and the `Statement` and the `Connection`, preferably by using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: You should not call `someResultSet.getObject(x + 1)` many times. Call it once and store it in a local variable. Every call likely creates a new object, so repeated calls will generate unnecessary garbage. And don't call `getDouble` if it is a `Double`. Just cast it.

Comment: Don't use `new BigDecimal(someValue)`. Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(someValue)` instead. See javadoc for why: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-. Better yet, don't use `BigDecimal` at all, since that generates unnecessary garbage. Use a `NumberFormat` instead (one that is initialized outside the loop).

Comment: I seriously doubt that using `new BigDecimal(someValue)` is causing the code to drag on as time progresses.

Comment: also, It appears that me forgetting to close the result sets is what was causing the issue.

Comment: Why do you seriously doubt that creating a *temporary* `BigDecimal` is causing the code to drag, if the main problem with your code is that GC is running too much, because of excessive garbage generation? Sure, the lack of resource cleanup is making it worse over time, but excessive garbage generation will cause more frequent GC runs, and that will slow down your server.

Comment: Because the data that is being processed has no numbers in it :/

Answer (score -1):

Simply this is happening due to memory getting full.
You should do 3 things:

1. Make them global. This way there will not be GC calling on every method exit. Memory will be allocated one time only and no relocation-delocation will takes place.

   ```
   List<Object[]> result;
   List<String> columnNames;
   List<Object> addRow;
   ```
2. At the end of "createFromResultSet" method, clear these lists. E.g.:

   ```
   addRow.clear();
   ```
3. Create "addRow = new ArrayList();" at the place of declaration itself.

   ```
   List<Object> addRow = new ArrayList();
   ```

Comment: Clearing a collection that is about to go out of scope accomplishes exactly nothing. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: EJP thanks for the formatting. Also please read all three steps. Clearing will be required when they are made global variables. Please do not downvote without reading complete text.